# C++ make tree node class as derivable with CRTP

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I wrote a node class for red-black trees as follows:

```
template <Containable T> struct RBTreeNode {
  T key_ = T{};
  RBTreeNode *parent_ = nullptr;
  bool black_ = false; // the new node starts out red
  std::unique_ptr<RBTreeNode> left_;
  std::unique_ptr<RBTreeNode> right_;
  RBTreeNode() = default;
  RBTreeNode(T key) : key_{std::move(key)} {}
  RBTreeNode(const RBTreeNode &node) = delete;
  RBTreeNode &operator=(const RBTreeNode &node) = delete;
  RBTreeNode(RBTreeNode &&node) = delete;
  RBTreeNode &operator=(RBTreeNode &&node) = delete;
};
```

This design works okay as-is, but as soon as I try to extend it to derived classes, this design becomes a big problem.

I want to extend `RBTreeNode` by adding some member variables from derived classes like this:

```
template <Containable T> struct RBOrderNode : public RBTreeNode<T> {
  using Base = RBTreeNode<T>;
  std::ptrdiff_t size_ = 1;
  RBOrderNode() = default;
  RBOrderNode(T key) : Base(std::move(key)) {}
};
```

but since `left_` and `right_` is `std::unique_ptr<RBTreeNode>`, traversing tree with referring `size_` member variables becomes impossible without using `virtual` or dynamic dispatch. This is of course, unacceptable.

I've used CRTP pattern several times before,
but it seems tricky to apply in this case.
How can I apply it in this situation?

**EDIT**: live demo: [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kYv7VOtVDEwFSp8l)

Comment: In order to extend RBTreeNode, you need to make it extensible, i.e. apply CRTP to *it*.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It doesn't work for resolving compile error for ```node->left_->size_```. Link: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dqths5T4PgXGYFX2

Comment: Solved.... https://wandbox.org/permlink/kYv7VOtVDEwFSp8l

Comment: It *probably* would be a lot easier to have `left_` and `right_` as pointers to `Derived`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Right, changing ```left_```, ```right_```, ```parent_``` as pointers to ```Derived``` solved a lot of headache